# What is this URL that loads each time Google Chrome spawns?

Tags: chrome, url

What does this URL do that opens each time Google Chrome loads?

> http://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/chromewebstore/L2Nocm9tZV9leHRlbnNpb24vYmxvYnMvOWVmQUFXS041NV9ZVXlJVWwxbGc5TUM4dw/7519.422.0.3_pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm.crx

You can see an example of this in app.any.run below:

[https://app.any.run/tasks/8ba5fb73-83ea-4439-8522-8eedf4b31024](http://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/chromewebstore/L2Nocm9tZV9leHRlbnNpb24vYmxvYnMvOWVmQUFXS041NV9ZVXlJVWwxbGc5TUM4dw/7519.422.0.3_pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm.crx)

I'm thinking this might be related to Chrome checking if extensions need updates.

Answer (score 0):

It's the URL used to download the [Chrome Cast extension](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/1165493270031536128) for Google Chrome.

Comment: Do you know why this tries to install each time Chrome launches? Does Chrome install the cast extension by default on launch each time?

Comment: @user3290171: not sure why; I guess it might be related to updating that extension.